# MVC2 Multi Select drop down list

Tags: asp.net-mvc-2

I have 2 multi-select Html.DropDownList controls with a button between them. When the user selects items from the first and presses the button they are copied to the second Html.DropDownList control via JQuery.

My problem is when the form is posted back I do not know how to obtain all the values in the second Html.DropDownList control.

This would be really easy with web forms but I have no idea how to do it with MVC2

thanks

--- Also I will need to validate the second Html.DropDownList to ensure it contains at least one item.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, I can get it to work by selecting all the items in the list with JavaScript right before the post back. This feels like such a hack to me though. Surely there is a better way to do it then this. Does anyone know of a way that does not rely on JavaScript?

If relying on JavaScript is the standard way to do this sort of thing then can someone explain why this is okay... Or is this an example of the immaturity of the MVC model?

Thanks.